# delete selected dropdown value in dynamic row

Tags: angular

I have parent dropdown with child dropdown value along with add button and delete button. If I have selected any value in dropdown then it should not render in another row dropdown while clicking on add button and when i click on delete button it should delete particular row with adding deleted dropdown value in previous dropdown list.

Adding and deleting value from dropdown/mat select using angular 6

[image]

component.html

Criteria
        
          
            
              
                {{select.columnName}}
              
            
          
        
        
          
            
              
                {{where.key}}

component.ts

```
constructor(private fb : FormBuilder,private service:ExpoCmsService,private 
http:HttpClient) {
  this.service.getSearchCmsData().subscribe(data=>{
   this.selects=data;
  })
  this.profileForm = this.fb.group({
    query:new FormControl('',Validators.required),
    optionGroups : this.fb.array([
        this.fb.group({
          selectInput : new FormControl('',Validators.required),
          whereInput : new FormControl('',Validators.required),

       }),
    ]),
  });

  onSelectSelect(selectInput: string , formIndex : number) : void {
      this.wheres[selectInput] = this.selects.filter((item)=> 
    item.columnName == selectInput);
    }

 public addOptionGroup(){
const fa = this.profileForm.controls["optionGroups"] as FormArray;
fa.push(this.newOptionGroup());

}
```

Comment: Where's your code?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to manage your data source at the time of selecting the value and when you add or remove the row.
you can get the change event by adding `(onSelectionChange)="change($event)"` on your select element in `.html` file like `<mat-option (onSelectionChange)="change($event)" ...... ></mat-option>`
then in your `.ts` file you can do the modification in the following function.

```
change(event)
  {
    if(event.isUserInput) {
     ....delete the data from data source....
    }
  }
```

Also, when you'll delete the row, you'll have to capture the item from mat select and put it back into the data source.

```
 delete(event)
          {
            ......add the data back to data source.....

             ....delete the row....
          }
```